# Чистый шаблон OpenCart

Tags: php, javascript, вёрстка, шаблоны, opencart

Здравствуйте!

Учусь верстать шаблоны под OpenCart. Подскажите, есть ли аналог чистого шаблона, как на Joomla или что-то подобное?

Думаю те кто верстал под OC понимают как там все заморочено.

Поделитесь опытом, есть ли программы, расширения или что-то подобное, что хоть как-то упрощает верстку под OC.

Comment: Выкиньте опенкарт, возьмите для обучения хотя бы вордпресс. На рынке едва ли найдется ПО хуже опенкарта.

Comment: @etki Найдется :) Но для новичка опенкарт и правда страшный сон (хотя для бывалых тоже). Одна только лапша из скриптов в страницах чего стоит. Они бы еще и стили все инлайнили прямо в теги

Answer (score 1):

Я тоже недавно начал верстать под OpenCart. Насколько смог разобраться, лучше не делать 100% чистый шаблон под OC, а вставлять туда свою разметку. Так меньше головной боли. Особенно что касается логики добавления товара в корзину, т.к. js-код там прямо в шаблоне. Поэтому аккуратно удалял стандартную разметку, добавляем свою и в неё врезки php-логики.